# Magento 2 - Change maximum order amount

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

I tried to check out the items in the cart that have more than 100.000.000 amount total.

And when I opened the View and Edit Cart, the checkout and multishipping checkout button disappeared because of the total value more than 100.000.000.

How can I change the maximum order amount so I can still check out even the total is more than 100.000.000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, first modify these tables columns :

> 1. value column in table: catalog_product_entity_decimal
> 2. price column in table:catalog_product_index_price
> 3. price column in table:catalog_product_index_price_tmp
> 4. price column in table:catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp

And then change the **MAXIMUM_AVAILABLE_NUMBER** in `/quote/model/QuoteValidator.php` to **9999999999**, and we could do checkout more than 1 million amount.

Source : [Here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-increase-maximum-amount-of-order-more-than-100-million/td-p/29845)

Answer (score 0):

This article may help you to maximize the order amount

http://blog.scuti.asia/2016/02/magento2-how-to-increase-maximum-price.html

The main idea of this blog that you need to alter some tables to modify the columns to be able to allow more than 100 millions.

even modify the table structure is not recommended but sometimes you don't have choice to do this.

a backup is highly required before doing such this actions

Comment: i already follow that instruction too, but it's still no use. But, i already change the max order to more than 1 million amount with change all the decimal(12,4) attribute to decimal(14,2) attribute, but the problem is, the checkout and multiple checkout button is not appear.

Answer (score 0):

change price/amount decimal (24,4) in **catalog_product_entity_decimal**, **catalog_product_index_price**, **catalog_product_index_price_tmp**, **catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp**,

change the MAXIMUM_AVAILABLE_NUMBER in /quote/model/QuoteValidator.php to 999999999999999,

And then Change decimal value (24,4) in all price/amount **quote** table and all price/amount **sales_order** table too..